# Symbolic Link: No such file or directory

Tags: symbolic-link

I created a symbolic Link from a File at "/opt/bladir/bla" to "bla". So "bla" is now in "/usr/bin/bla". But if I want to call "bla" at terminal, there comes the no such file or directory error. I looked up at "/usr/bin/bla" and the file is linking correctly at "/opt/bladir/bla".

What can be the error?

P.S. here is my terminal "entry":  `sudo ln -s /opt/bladir/bla bla`

Thanks!

€: Problem solved. According to the Feature List, 12.04 should have Multiarch support... 'should'. I got the ia32-libs from synaptic and now the program wents just fine. As it looks, my symbolic links where correct.

Thank you for all the answers!

Comment: Just for the record: I got the same error. My problem was, that I was sitting in a deleted folder. To fix it: go out of the deleted folder, recreate the deleted folder, go into the new folder, try to create the symlink -> worked. ;)

Comment: To copy a broken symlink: `cp --no-dereference "theBroken" "theBroken.BKP # -P"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

EDIT: the solution below does not work. It is apparent that the symbolic link is broken, because `file -L` cannot open the symbolic link /usr/bin/bla. In this case, do the following:

```
sudo ln -sf /opt/bladir/bla /usr/bin/bla
```

using full paths (-f is to force overwriting the previous symbolic link, if there is one).

Hm. I think that the program "bla" may be looking for things that are installed in /opt/bladir and cannot find them. For example, it can be a shell script wrapper around a Java executable, with path relative to current directory: but your current directory is /usr/bin/, and not /opt/bladir/.

If the following works

```
file -L /usr/bin/bla
```

...then it is *definitely* not a problem with your symbolic link.

Check whether "bla" is a shell script that you can modify, take a look inside -- maybe you will find the problem. Possibly, adding /opt/bladir to your PATH would be a better solution.

Comment: The given command says: ERROR: cannot open `/usr/bin/bla'. I can't take a look inside "bla", it's a program, not only a shell script.

Comment: OK, redo the symbolic link with full paths, please.

Comment: I came to that idea earlier by myself. Even with rm the old links and creating new ones, the error still appears. -sf also did not work.

Comment: OK. Plese run `ls -l /usr/bin/bla` and `ls -l /opt/bladir/bla` and report the exact output of these commands.

Comment: @January what course of action would you recommend if `file -L` *doesn't* work?

Comment: figured it out.  problem was i'd created my symlinks with wildcards -- e.g., `ln -s files* new_dir/`.

Comment: If it doesn't work try with full file path both the side (actual file and the link file)

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you had a different problem than me since you said,

"I looked up at "/usr/bin/bla" and the file is linking correctly at "/opt/bladir/bla"."

However, for others coming here, I wanted to put ~/julia-1.5.3/bin/julia on PATH via symlink, so I basically did `cd /home/username/` and then `sudo ln -s julia-1.5.3/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia`. When I typed `julia`, it said `bash: /usr/local/bin/julia: No such file or directory`. When I did `ls -all /usr/local/bin`, I found the issue; it was linking to the dangling relative directory: `julia -> julia-1.5.3/bin/julia`.

Anyway, I just had to redo it with the absolute path, and it worked:
`sudo ln -sf /home/username/julia-1.5.3/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the case for this question, but another situation where this error could happen is if one of the directories has a space in it and isn't surrounded in quotation marks. for example:

```
ln -s my home/username/myfolder/a file.txt file.txt
```

will cause an error. but

```
ln -s my "home/username/myfolder/a file.txt" file.txt
```

will not.

Answer (score 1):

Often this type of error message is shown, if you don't have execution bit enabled. Check whether the main file as well as the link is given execution permission.

I'm suspecting your `/opt` may be mounted from a separate partition and it isn't mounted with `exec` mount option

Comment: The excecution bit is set and /opt/ is not on a separate partition :/