# Problem with environment variables

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I tried creating a shortcut to easily change into some of my Windows partitions. After mounting them, some works fine, some not. Here's what happens.

My `~/.bash_aliases` contains:

```
export geo=/media/geo/Novo\ volume/Geo
export windows=/media/geo/OS/Users/Geo
```

When I type in terminal

```
geo@george-Ubuntu:~$ cd $windows
geo@george-Ubuntu:/media/geo/OS/Users/Geo$
```

it works as expected.

However, when I try:

```
geo@george-Ubuntu:/media/geo/OS/Users/Geo$ cd $geo
bash: cd: /media/geo/Novo: No such file or directory
```

It can't find the directory (made sure that "Novo Volume" is mounted and the directory exists)

How can I fix this? [Symbolic Link: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193670/symbolic-link-no-such-file-or-directory) Didn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see:

```
bash: cd: /media/geo/Novo: No such file or directory
```

since you tried to set a variable for the folder `"/media/geo/Novo volume/Geo"` (with a space) and the error is about **only the first part of the path up to the space**, you see, that the space is wrongly treated as separator.

If you want to use

```
cd $geo
```

yuo could have to include the quotes in the string:

```
export geo='"/media/geo/Novo volume/Geo"'
```

which isn't a good solution, a better approach is to set an alias in your `.bash_aliases` for example:

```
alias cd-geo='cd "/media/geo/Novo volume/Geo"'
alias cd-windows='cd /media/geo/OS/Users/Geo'
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is quoting the variable, since it contains a space character.

```
cd "$geo"
```

Quoting variables which might contain spaces is always good practice in shell code.

Answer (score 1):

Stolen from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3911099/3665278) If you do `cd "$geo"` I'll bet you get the right result

That being said, try doing

`alias geo="cd /media/geo/OS/Users/Geo"` and then just using `geo` (as a command) to go there.